# Configure popper.js orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, popper.js

Is it possible to configure orientation on a popover through popper.js?

Like, showing it aligned right, but going towards left?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs often when your parent container is not wide enough to receive popover content.

At the moment, I'm dealing with it by disabling `preventOverflow` like this :

```
new Popper(ref, pop, {
  modifiers: {
    preventOverflow: { enabled: false }
  }
})
```